# unicorn fails when started by capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

When I start unicorn via capistrano task and try to access my app I get this

```
tarted GET "/" for xx.xxx.xxx at 2012-08-11 01:38:31 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 87ms
** [Bugsnag] No API key configured, couldn't notify

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass):
    32:               </form>
    33:             </ul>
    34:           <ul class="nav pull-right">
    35:             <% if user_signed_in? %>
    36:               <li class="dropdown">
    37:                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    38:                   <%= current_user.name %>
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `user_signed_in?'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:35:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3931886679734892787_26070680'
```

in addition of `ActionView::Template::Error`, unicorn says that no busgnag API key configured, but I've already set the key on my root's .bashrc and deploy's .bashrc (deploy is a user too)
but when I access the server via ssh like `ssh root@server` and try to start unicorn with the same command the capistrano's task issued, everythin works fine...
I've tried to set root user on capistrano and deploy user, both with `use_sudo` true and false...
What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure when you run it manually you are running in production mode? `undefined method`xxxx' for nil:NilClass` happens when you have an nil variable. Often times code like...

```
Articles.each do |article|
  article.title
end
```

Will fails with the same error because the db is populated differently in each environment. I would suggest looking at line 5 `application_controller.rb` and seeing if that variable is present in both production and development.

Also, make sure that your bugsnap api key is available in your `production.rb` file.

Comment: I'm starting via foreman, like this: `web: bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn/production.rb -E production`. I didn't put bugsnag api key on production, I'm using environment variables. I've added these variables to `.bashrc` file

Comment: Had to put my ENVs on `environment.rb` file :)